# Alignment of the string in C

Tags: c

How to create the left and right aligned printout of the string by placing exactly the required number of characters (including white spaces) per line.

For example, given:

```
Hello world! And so on
```

output should be:

```
Hello    world!   And   so    on
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do [Justified alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment#Justified) (adding spaces inside each line so that they are all the same length)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can start with:

```
 function strReplace(char str[]) {
   char s[STR_LEN);

   int i;
   for(i = 0, j = 0; i < STR_LEN; ++i, ++j) {
     if(str[i++] == ' ') s[j++] = '\t';
     s[j] = str[i];
   }
 }
```

what this will do is insert `\t' into string instead of ' ' which in turn will add up to n spaces and alight each word like to form of a grid.

Comment: Thank you,  it didn't work for me but your answer give me idea how to do this

Comment: x=skipedPlaces;
   while(skipedPlaces!=0)
    {
    for(int i=0,j=0; i<num-skipedPlaces; i++,j++)
     {
     if (string[i]==' '&& string[i+1]!=' '&& skipedPlaces!=0)
      {
      str[j]=string[i];
      j++;
      str[j]=' ';
      skipedPlaces--;
      }
     else
     str[j]=string[i];
     if (skipedPlaces!=0 && i==num-(x-1))
      {
      i=0;j=0;
      for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
       {
       string[i]=str[i];
       }
      }
     }